# Calling javascript function on success of 4-5 Ajax Calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, extjs, q

I am need to make 4-5 Ajax calls and once all these calls are successful I need to call a JavaScript function. I am using ExtJS. I can make these Ajax calls by using JQuery as well.

How can I call a function once all these Ajax calls are successful.

I can created 4-5 flags &  on success of every ajax call, I will set respective flag to true & once all the flags are true, I will make the function call.

Is there any better way to achieve desired result.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the jQuery `when`:

```
$.when(
    // Get first
    $.get("/first/", function(result) {
        //Do something with result
    }),

    // Get second
    $.get("/second/", function(result) {
        //Do something with result
    }),

    // Get third
    $.get("/third/", function(result) {
        //Do something with result
    })

).then(function() {
    // All is ready now, so...
});
```

Source:
http://css-tricks.com/multiple-simultaneous-ajax-requests-one-callback-jquery/

It's also documented on the jquery site:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: I don't want to make these Ajax call one by one. I want to make all these call at the same time and then once all the calls returns success, I will to call my function. This looks like will make calls one after another.

Comment: The requests will be ran in parallel (which is obvious if you realize the `$.get` method is called 3 times before the `$.when` method itself is called... so it could no nothing to synchronize the requests). You should also add a second function to `then`, in order to handle failure.

Comment: $.get() is always asynchronous unless specified not to be.